# CGI + long POST content / requests = defunct process and 502 page

Tags: iis, cgi

we noticed a strange problem / misbehavior of IIS 7.5 + CGI module.

when POSTing long content (50k+ bytes) to an CGI exe, IIS is not sending
the full content to our CGI exe via STDIN.

the length of the content that IIS is sending to the exe is not of fixed size, so it
might not be an buffer size problem, etc!

the cgi exe behaves as following:

1. get the content length of the HTTP header
2. read as much bytes from STDIN as specified in content length
3. do some magic work and exit

as not all bytes are forwarded by IIS / CGI module to our exe file,
the exe file / process is running "forever" and is not returning
any content. the process is killed after some minutes (timeout).

any suggestions / hints / etc. ... thanks in advance

regards,
mherderich

Comment: not solved yet. it seems that only a few other people are having this issue/problem ... :(

Answer (score 0):

This can be the common Windows CR+LF problem. The content length may not be accurate when CR+LF translation is done, as CR+LF is translated to the single chàracter `\n`.